# NAudio - WaveOut doesn't raise PlaybackStopped event when used with WaveOffsetStream

Tags: audio, naudio

When you create a `WaveOut` object, and initialize it with `WaveOffsetStream`, the `PlaybackStopped` event is not raised at the end of the playback. Code:

```
WaveOut myWaveOut = new WaveOut();
myWaveOut.PlaybackStopped += OnPlaybackStopped;

WaveOffsetStream OffsetStream = new WaveOffsetStream(MyOtherStream);

myWaveOut.Init(OffsetStream);
myWaveOut.Play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WaveOutOffsetStream` always returns the requested number of bytes from `Read` so it is a never-ending stream. You'd have to use something different, or detect when the `Position` went past the point you wanted to play to